# Room database Error: IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify

Tags: android, database, kotlin, runtime-error

I have been getting this error as of lately while using room database. It tells me to upgrader the room version, but when I do this I get another error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

This is what I get when changing the database version number from: version = 1 -> version = 2.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: That means that the database that you now have has a different schema of your data, that is why it need to apply a migration or allow for destructive (The error seems to say it all)

Comment: You either delete your database or apply the function addMigration to apply the migrations needed

Comment: So if I delete the db I have atm, it will still be able to save/store the information ?

Comment: If your delete the db you have, you will lose all the information stored atm, then Room will create a new one when you use it. If you don't want to lose data you need a migration, for more info https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

Comment: alright will read up about it on your link, appreciate the feedback!

Comment: there is 1 thing I dont understand though, how come this only happens to 1 database (in my case called Age database ) and not another databases ? @RuiAlves

Comment: without more information I can't answer, there is various scenarios where this can happen